# Ajax Call to spring servlet could not initiate oauth2 dance for IBM connection cloud

Tags: ibm-sbt

I am trying to make an ajax call from my web page to my spring servlet which then has to retrive the data from connections cloud using SBT oauth2 endpoint. The ajax call is working fine for other servlets but failing to do oauth2 dance.

Here is my ajax function in jquery.

```
      $.ajax({
        url: 'getmycontacts',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(res) {

            alert("in success");
            console.log(res);
            document.getElementById('returnmsg').innerHTML = res;
            alert(res);
        },            
        error : function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError){
        console.log("in error");
             console.log(xhr.responseText);
             console.log("status code.."+(xhr.status));
        }
    });
```

Java servlet

```
    @RequestMapping(value ="/getmycontacts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody String getmycontacts(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response){


      String message ;

        try {  
            ProfileService service = new ProfileService("smartcloudOA2"); //If no endpoint is specified, it uses default end point i.e connections
            ProfileList profiles = service.getMyContacts();
            String id = service.getMyProfile().getDisplayName(); 
            if(profiles!=null && !profiles.isEmpty())
            {
                 message = id;

            }
            else { message ="no result"; }

    } catch (Throwable e) {
         message = e.getMessage();
    }   



    return message ;
```

I get the following error

```
> [err] java.lang.IllegalStateException [err]   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendRedirectWithStatusCode(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:573)
> [err]     at [internal classes] [err]     at
> com.ibm.commons.runtime.impl.servlet.ContextServlet.sendRedirect(ContextServlet.java:76)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth2Handler.performOAuth2Dance(OAuth2Handler.java:791)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth2Handler._acquireToken(OAuth2Handler.java:567)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth2Handler.acquireToken(OAuth2Handler.java:521)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.OAuth2Endpoint.authenticate(OAuth2Endpoint.java:95)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.forceAuthentication(ClientService.java:296)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.processResponse(ClientService.java:1154)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService._xhr(ClientService.java:1072)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.execRequest(ClientService.java:1037)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.xhr(ClientService.java:997)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:873)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:869)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:859)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:854)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.smartcloud.profiles.ProfileService.getMyProfile(ProfileService.java:109)
> [err]     at
> com.bluefizz.controller.Getcontacts.getmycontacts(Getcontacts.java:35)
> [err]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> [err]     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
> [err]     at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
> [err]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620) [err]   at
> org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
> [err]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
> [err]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
> [err]     at [internal classes] [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.util.SBTFilter.doFilter(SBTFilter.java:53) [err]  at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
> [err]     at [internal classes] [err]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
> [err]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
> [err]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798) [err]
> java.lang.IllegalStateException [err]     at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendRedirectWithStatusCode(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:573)
> [err]     at [internal classes] [err]     at
> com.ibm.commons.runtime.impl.servlet.ContextServlet.sendRedirect(ContextServlet.java:76)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth2Handler.performOAuth2Dance(OAuth2Handler.java:791)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth2Handler._acquireToken(OAuth2Handler.java:567)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth2Handler.acquireToken(OAuth2Handler.java:521)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.OAuth2Endpoint.authenticate(OAuth2Endpoint.java:95)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.forceAuthentication(ClientService.java:296)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.processResponse(ClientService.java:1154)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService._xhr(ClientService.java:1072)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.execRequest(ClientService.java:1037)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.xhr(ClientService.java:997)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:873)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:869)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:859)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.get(ClientService.java:854)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.smartcloud.profiles.ProfileService.getMyProfile(ProfileService.java:109)
> [err]     at
> com.bluefizz.controller.Getcontacts.getmycontacts(Getcontacts.java:35)
> [err]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> [err]     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
> [err]     at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
> [err]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620) [err]   at
> org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
> [err]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
> [err]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
> [err]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
> [err]     at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
> [err]     at [internal classes] [err]     at
> com.ibm.sbt.util.SBTFilter.doFilter(SBTFilter.java:53) [err]  at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
> [err]     at [internal classes] [err]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
> [err]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
> [err]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798)
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>Bluefizz</display-name>
    <filter>
        <display-name>SBTFilter</display-name>
        <filter-name>SBTFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.ibm.sbt.util.SBTFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>false</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SBTFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>
        /SBTFilter</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SBTFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>
        /*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>ServiceServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.sbt.service.core.servlet.ServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <async-supported>false</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/getmycontacts</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
    <description>Reference to a URL resource which points to the configuration properties for the Social Business Toolkit.</description>
    <res-ref-name>url/ibmsbt-sbtproperties</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>java.net.URL</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>



    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>LibraryServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>LibraryServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.sbt.jslibrary.servlet.LibraryServlet</servlet-class>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <async-supported>false</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
        /ServiceServlet</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>
        /service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LibraryServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
        /LibraryServlet</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>
        /library/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Also the servlet is working correctly when the request is sent directly from the browser such as form submit.

Comment: what does your web.xml look like?

Comment: @PaulBastide I just added my web.xml file.

Comment: Your spring code is wrapping and forcing the SBT code into a pure java role.  The pure java role will not enable the OAuth functions to work which requires SBTFilter.  What you want will not work.  You should run this as a separate servlet or jsp

Comment: @PaulBastide But why is my servlet working when it is a browser request?

Comment: @raven how did you manage this?